# ¿Cómo insertar valores de dos radio button con PHP y MySQL?

Tags: php, html, mysql, web

lo que pasa es que tengo un pequeño problema al momento de guardar valores de dos radio button en una base de datos MySQL. Al momento de guardar los datos en la bd, me aparece un mensaje llamado "on" en las filas, ¿Que querrá decir eso? Porqué no se están guardando los datos?

formulario.php

```
***
```

> ```
> <div class="wrapper">
>               <h2>Planificación de la Faena</h2>
>               <div class="form-conteniar">
>                   <form action="php/form1_faena.php" method="POST">
>                       <div class="input-name">
>                           <label>Tipo de Personal:</label><br><br>
>                           <input type="radio" name="radiogroup1" id="ravi" class="radio-button">
>                           <label for="ravi" class="personal">Personal de Instalación</label>
>                           <input type="radio" name="radiogroup1" id="ravi1" class="radio-button">
>                           <label for="ravi1" class="contratista">Personal Contratista</label>
>                       </div>
>                       <div class="input-name">
>                           <label>Tipo de Instalación:</label><br><br>
>                           <input type="radio" name="radiogroup2" id="ravi2" class="radio">
>                           <label for="ravi2" class="desenergizada">Instalación desenergizada</label><br>
>                           <input type="radio" name="radiogroup2" id="ravi3" class="radio">
>                           <label for="ravi3" class="energizada">Instalación energizada</label>
>                       </div>
>                       <div class="input-name">
>                           <i class="fa fa-building companyy" aria-hidden="true"></i>
>                           <input type="text" placeholder="Planta Perteneciente" class="company" name="planta">
>                       </div>
>                       <div class="input-name">
>                           <i class="fa fa-cogs" aria-hidden="true"></i>
>                           <input type="text" placeholder="Puesto de Trabajo" class="puesto" name="puesto">
>                       </div>
>                       <div class="input-name">
>                           <i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i>
>                           <input type="text" class="fecha" id="datetime" placeholder="Seleccionar Fecha y Hora" name="fecha">
>                       </div>
>                       <div class="input-name">
>                           <select class="trabajo" name="tipo">
>                               <option>Seleccionar el tipo de trabajo</option>
>                               <option>Bomba de agua</option>
>                               <option>Ventilador de aire</option>
>                               <option>Mantenimiento de Maquinarias</option>
>                           </select>
>                           <div class="arrow"></div>
>                       </div>
>                       <div class="input-name">
>                           <select class="ubicacion" name="ubicacion">
>                               <option>Seleccionar Ubicación</option>
>                               <option>Caldera</option>
>                               <option>Turbinas</option>
>                               <option>Molinos</option>
>                           </select>
>                           <div class="arrow1"></div>
>                       </div>
>                       <div class="input-name">
>                           <input class="button" type="submit" value="Registrar" name="insert" >
>                       </div>
>                   </form>
>               </div>
>           </div>
> ```

---

form1_faena.php

***<?php

```
include 'conexion_be.php';

    $tipo_personal = $_POST['radiogroup1'];
    $tipo_instalacion = $_POST['radiogroup2'];
    $planta = $_POST['planta'];
    $puesto = $_POST['puesto'];
    $fecha = $_POST['fecha'];
    $tipo_trabajo = $_POST['tipo'];
    $ubicacion = $_POST['ubicacion'];

    $query = "INSERT INTO planificacion_faena(tipo_personal, tipo_instalacion, planta, puesto_trabajo, fecha, tipo_trabajo, ubicacion) VALUES('$tipo_personal', '$tipo_instalacion', '$planta', '$puesto', '$fecha', '$tipo_trabajo', '$ubicacion')";

    $ejecutar = mysqli_query($conexion, $query);

    if ($ejecutar) {
        echo '<script>
                alert("Datos ingresados correctamente");
                window.location = "../formulario-php"
        </script>';
    }else{
        echo '<script>
        alert("Error, Inténtalo de nuevo");
        window.location = "../formulario.php";
    </script>';
    }


?>******
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se ve en la imagen, aparece el mensaje que mencioné anteriormente, los otros valores si se guardan, pero no los que corresponden a los dos radiobutton.

Comment: Lo primero que noto y que por eso no recibes valores es que no tienes un atributo value con algún valor asignado en esos inputs

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas ponerle el value a tu radiobuttons

```
<input type="radio" name="radiogroup1" id="ravi" class="radio-button" value="Contratista">
<input type="radio" name="radiogroup1" id="ravi1" class="radio-button" value="Instalación">
```